# Xamarin forms scroll to buttom

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am creation an Xamarin foms app where I will have messages coming over time, and I always want the new messages to show on the button of my ListView as they are coming in.

At the moment my page looks like this:

```
 <StackLayout>
   <Button  Text="Login"  />
   <ListView  x:Name="MessageBox" ItemsSource="{Binding TempTest}" ></ListView>
   <Button Command="{Binding AddMessage}" Text="Login"/>
 </StackLayout>
```

I cant figure out how to scroll from my ViewModel class, any ideas about how to achieve this?

The best that I have been able to find so far are this: http://www.infinite-x.net/2014/10/30/using-the-xamarin-forms-1-3-0-listview-scrollto-method/

But he is not even thinking about using MVVM at this stage.

Comment: Are you trying to scroll to one of the `Button`s? Both `Button`s you have in your code are outside of the `ListView` so they would not be able to be scrolled to.

Comment: My buttons have a command binded to another class, from that class I add new messages to my view.

After adding the message I want to scroll the view so that the full message is visible (not mater how many messages that I add to the scroll view)

Comment: Do you mean scrolling to _button_ or _bottom_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the one, less than elegant way, I would know to solve that would be to expose an `Action<Message>` from your ViewModel and then your `ContentPage` would initialize that `Action` and tell it to do the scrolling. Something like the following (just replace `Message` with what ever the real model name is).

ContentPage:

```
public partial class MessagePage : ContentPage {

    private MessageViewModel _viewModel;

    public MessagePage() {
        _viewModel = new MessageViewModel();

        BindingContext = _viewModel;

        _viewModel.OnMessageAdded = message => { //We tell the action to scroll to the passed in object here
            MessageBox.ScrollTo(message, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, true);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MessageViewModel {
    public Action<Message> OnMessageAdded { get; set; }

    public ICommand AddMessage { get; protected set; }

    private ObservableCollection<Message> _tempTest;
    public  ObservableCollection<Message> TempTest {
        get { return _tempTest ?? (_tempTest = new ObservableCollection<Message>()); }
        set {
            if(_tempTest != value) {
                _tempTest = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public MessageViewModel() {
        AddMessage = new Command(async () => {
            Message message = SomeClass.GetMessage(); //Get your object from your separate class

            TempTest.Add(message); //Add it to the list that your ListView binds to

            OnMessageAdded?.Invoke(message); //Now run the Action which, if it is not null, your ContentPage should have set to do the scrolling

            //Or if you are not using C#6:
            //Action<Message> onMessageAdded = OnMessageAdded;

            //if(onMessageAdded != null) { onMessageAdded.Invoke(message); }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using something like what you recommended, thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminKarlog Glad it helped out.