# How to use ScrollTo method on a Listview

Tags: listview, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I have xamarin forms app which uses prism. I'm using a `ListView`  which is bound to an `ObservableCollection<string>`, however whenever the listview opens again , it needs to scroll to previously selected item from the listview.

There is a method ScrollTo but how would I implement it using prism?

Could you please help me out with this issue?

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding obsCommonList}" HasUnevenRows="True" BackgroundColor="Black" SeparatorVisibility="None" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProp,Mode=TwoWay}">
      <ListView.Behaviors>
          <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}"  EventArgsParameterPath="Item"/>
      </ListView.Behaviors>
```

Comment: You can refer this link. 
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/40452064/5293268]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like the following:

Start with making the EventAggregator available in the resources so that you can add this to a behavior property in your XAML.

```
public class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        Resources.Add("eventAggregator", Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>());
        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage");
    }
}
```

Create an event that takes the model type that you have in your ObservableCollection

```
public class ScrollToMyModelEvent : PubSubEvent<MyModel>
{
}
```

Add a Behavior with a property for the IEventAggregator. *NOTE* You don't need the property to be a Bindable Property, or really observable. What you really need is to make sure you subscribe to the event when the EventAggregator is set.

```
public class ScrollToMyModelBehavior : BehaviorBase<ListView>
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    public IEventAggregator EventAggregator
    {
        get => _eventAggregator;
        set
        {
            if(!EqualityComparer<IEventAggregator>.Default.Equals(_eventAggregator, value))
            {
                _eventAggregator = value;
                _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ScrollToMyModelEvent>().Subscribe(OnScrollToEventPublished);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnScrollToEventPublished(MyModel model)
    {
        AssociatedObject.ScrollTo(model, ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(ListView bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        // The Event Aggregator uses weak references so forgetting to do this
        // shouldn't create a problem, but it is a better practice.
        EventAggregator.GetEvent<ScrollToMyModelEvent>().Unsubscribe(OnScrollToEventPublished);
    }
}
```

In your ViewModel, you now simply need to publish the event. You can do as I show here where you only do this when you Navigate Back to the View. This would then be handled in the Behavior and pass it into the ListView's ScrollTo method.

```
public class MyListPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigatedAware
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator { get; }

    public MyListPageViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }

    public MyModel SelectedModel { get; set; }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters)
    {
        if(parameters.GetNavigationMode() == NavigationMode.Back && 
           SelectedModel != null)
        {
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ScrollToMyModelEvent>()
                            .Publish(SelectedModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your View

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:behavior="clr-namespace:AwesomeApp.Behaviors" 
             x:Class="AwesomeApp.ScrollToPage">
    <ListView>
        <ListView.Behaviors>
            <behavior:ScrollToMyModelBehavior EventAggregator="{StaticResource eventAggregator}" />
        </ListView.Behaviors>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, In the behavior class the _OnAttachBehaviorChanged_ method of the _AttachBehaviorProperty_ gets fired , however I'm not able to subscribe to the event as _OnAttachBehaviorChanged_  is static

Can you please take a look at my behavior class: 
[link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/eb01517dbec43a0d0ae0d0fcbc73c857)

Comment: Please see the revision to the Behavior. You don't need anything static in the class at all :)

Comment: This works Dan, thanks alot for the solution and detailed explanation.

Comment: @DanS.Hi. Two things that are my problem. What is the Mymodel? I've changed Mymodel name with the class contains Observable Collection items. So by starting the project raises this error:"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I have used containerRegistry.Register<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>("eventAggregator"); instead but error "StaticResource not found for key eventAggregator" raised

Comment: @Behzad the example would expect that you’ve registered the EventAgregator in a ResourceDictionary. You could easily resolve the service and add it to the App Resources in your OnInitialized method.

Comment: @DanS. Hi. As you said I did this: "Resources.Add("eventAggregator", Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>());  " but it raises Null exception

Comment: @DanS. Could you have a look in to this question please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51577815/prism-null-exception-on-container-resolveieventaggregator