# prism null exception on Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>()

Tags: xamarin.forms, eventaggregator

The line Resources.Add("eventAggregator", Container.Resolve()); raises Null exception.

**UPDATE**
I've added all classes to explain more. As @Axemasta said, there is no need to register IEventAggregator and I removed registration. Now I don't how to connect the Listview EventAggregator behavior to the EventAggregator.

This is whole App.xaml code file.

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    /* 
     * The Xamarin Forms XAML Previewer in Visual Studio uses System.Activator.CreateInstance.
     * This imposes a limitation in which the App class must have a default constructor. 
     * App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) cannot be handled by the Activator.
     */
    public App() : this(null) { }


    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer) : base(initializer) { }

    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Resources.Add("eventAggregator", Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>());// Removed on update

        FlowListView.Init();

        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");

    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {            
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage>();           
    }
}
```

}

The behavior class:

```
public class ScrollToMyModelBehavior : BehaviorBase<ListView>
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    public IEventAggregator EventAggregator
    {
        get => _eventAggregator;
        set
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<IEventAggregator>.Default.Equals(_eventAggregator, value))
            {
                _eventAggregator = value;
                _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ScrollToMyModelEvent>().Subscribe(OnScrollToEventPublished);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnScrollToEventPublished(ListItem model)
    {
        AssociatedObject.ScrollTo(model, ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(ListView bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        // The Event Aggregator uses weak references so forgetting to do this
        // shouldn't create a problem, but it is a better practice.
        EventAggregator.GetEvent<ScrollToMyModelEvent>().Unsubscribe(OnScrollToEventPublished);
    }
}
```

The Event class:

```
public class ScrollToMyModelEvent : PubSubEvent<ListItem>
{
}
```

The page view model:

```
        public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IEventAggregator eventAggregator) 
        : base (navigationService)
    {
        Title = "صفحه اصلی";
        ListHeight = 100;
        ListWidth = 250;

        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        Items items = new Items();
        ListViewItemSouce = items.GetItems();

        MyModels = items.GetItems();
        SelectedModel = ListViewItemSouce[3];
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ScrollToMyModelEvent>().Publish(SelectedModel);
    }
```

The page view:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="{Binding ListWidth}" HeightRequest="{Binding ListHeight}"
                         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <local:NativeListView x:Name="lst3" ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItemSouce}" Margin="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" RowHeight="47" HasUnevenRows="false">
                    <ListView.Behaviors>
                        <local:ScrollToMyModelBehavior EventAggregator="{StaticResource eventAggregator}" /> // Error raised that there is not such a static property
                    </ListView.Behaviors>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextCell Text="{Binding Word}"  TextColor="Black"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </local:NativeListView>
            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: To use the event aggregator, you don't need to register it. You will need to have an event (inherit from `PubSubEvent`), then you can just pass it into your viewmodels/views and subscribe/publish events!

Comment: Thanks, is there any simple example?

Comment: I will provide a full use case as an answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to register `IEventAggregator` when the app initialises, much like `INavigationService` or `IPageDialog`, you can use it straight out of the box!

To use `EventAggregator` you should do the following things:

**Create an Event**

You will first need to create an Event (using Prism) that you can pass to the `EventAggregator`. Your event should inherit from `PubSubEvent`, you can pass this an object (optional). So your event would look like this:

```
using System;
using Prism.Events;

namespace Company.App.Namespace.Events
{
    public class SampleEvent : PubSubEvent
    {
    }
}
```

Looking at a recent app, I most commonly use this when passing data between custom popup views (like a dictionary of params).

**Subscribe to the Event**

When `IEventAggregator` fires, anything that has subscribe to the event will execute any code specified. In the class you want to recieved the event you will have to do the following:

- Pass the class `IEventAggregator` through the constructor (prism does the DI afterall)
- Initialise a local `IEventAggregator` for use in this class
- Subscribe `IEventAggregator` to a handler method.

Here is what the code may look like:

```
public class TheClassListeningForAnEvent
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public TheClassListeningForAnEvent(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<SampleEvent>().Subscribe(OnEventRecieved);
    }

    void OnEventRecieved()
    {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

**Fire the Event**

Now you have registered for the event, you can fire the event. Pass the `IEventAggregator` into whatever class you want to fire the event from and use the `Publish Method`:

```
public class TheClassPublishingAnEvent
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public TheClassListeningForAnEvent(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<SampleEvent>().Publish();
    }
}
```

Thats the long and the short of it. You could pass anything to the `IEventAggregator`, you would just need to handle for this in the methods you are subscribing.

Hopefully that is enough to get you going using `IEventAggregator`!

Comment: Thanks man. I've updated the question. The problem is how to connect to the event from xaml listiew?!

Comment: Hi @Behzad you could apply an `x:Name` to your listview and then subscribe a method in codebehind to scroll to where you need to go by directly referencing the listview

Comment: this way is not an MVVM way, isn't It? because we are using codeBehinde

Comment: @Behzad Using codebehind doesn't break MVVM necessarily. You can write MVVM apps in pure codebehind (all the concepts are the same). If your viewmodel is doing view related things then you are breaking MVVM. The whole thing is that a view knows about a view model but a view model doesn't know about a view. Sometimes you need to use the codebehind to do things xamarin forms won't let you do normally!

Answer (score 0):

Just verify if you are adding below code in IOS, Android and UWP projects.

IOS- Appdelegate

```
public class AppdelegateInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
    {
        public void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {

        }
    }
```

Android - MainActivity

```
public class MainActivityInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
    {
        public void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {

        }
    }
```

UWP-- MainPage.cs

```
public class UwpInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
    {
        public void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guidance on this has evolved as features have been added to Prism to make this sort of thing even easier.

In the past the reason you would resolve and add the IEventAggregator as a StaticResource is that there was no way to inject this. We now have the ContainerProvider which amazingly allows you to add types in XAML that require Dependency Injection. To start you can refactor your ScrollToBehavior to use a DI Pattern by adding the `IEventAggregator` as a constructor parameter, removing the Bindable Property (if you choose).

```
public class ScrollToBehavior : BehaviorBase<ListView>
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator { get; }

    public ScrollToBehavior(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }
}
```

As I mentioned you can use the `ContainerProvider` in XAML to resolve and provide a type that requires DI, as follows:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ioc="clr-namespace:Prism.Ioc;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:behavior="using:AwesomeProject.Behaviors
             x:Class="AwesomeProject.Views.ViewA">
  <ListView>
    <ListView.Behaviors>
      <ioc:ContainerProvider x:TypeArguments="behavior:ScrollToBehavior" />
    </ListView.Behaviors>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: thanks. Are sure that this line is correct? <ioc:ContainerProvider x:TypeArguments="behavior:ScrollToBehavior" />

Comment: Type ioc:ContainerProvider not found in xmlns clr-namespace:Prism.ioc;assembly=Prism.Forms

Comment: what version are you using? it doesn't matter what container you're using since we abstracted DI container in Prism 7

Comment: The Prism is 7 and I can't using Prism.Ioc yet

Comment: If you’re still on Prism 6 you cannot use this feature as it wasn’t introduced until v7

Comment: as I said, I'm using Prism 7.1.0.172-pre . Does it need any Nuget?

Comment: Sorry I read your comment out of context. The Container Provider is in the Prism.Forms assembly and uses the IoC abstraction to resolve your type. It really doesn’t matter what container you use because it ultimately comes from that container anyway. You can use it in any project directly or indirectly referencing Prism.Forms. So if you are using the new PackageReference you just need a reference to Prism.{Your Container}.Forms.

Comment: Type ioc:ContainerProvider not found in xmlns clr-namespace:Prism.Ioc;assembly=Prism.Forms

Comment: @Behzad you have no repo app... I cannot tell you what you are doing wrong. What I can do is point you at a [XAML View](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.DI.Forms.Tests/Mocks/Views/XamlViewMock.xaml) in the Mocks that we use to unit test this. I suggest you look at this for guidance.